# Calling external variables from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can we call a extern variable like NSBeginAlertSheet from Swift.

In my project, I need to use a framework which has this extern variales defined and the code for the same is written in objective C.
Its very easy to call the same from another objective C project, However I am not able to call the same from Swift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: click on link to know about how to use Obj C within Swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Obj c in Swift you want to create bridging header file and import any .h file which you want to use in swift project

click on link to know about how to use Obj C within Swift [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)